# Very slow page loads

Tags: plugins, themes, database

I've inherited a wordpress site using the Avada theme and page loads seems to be exceptionally slow, anywhere from seven seconds to 30 seconds. It looks to me like one or more of the queries are doing something very strange, since there's a long list in the slow query monitor.

It's WordPress 5.2.6 running Avada theme.

Here is an example of some of the query data:

UPDATE `wp_options`
SET `option_value` = 'a:8:{s:28:\"enable_builder_ui_by_default\";s:1:\"1\";s:15:\"fusion_elements\";a:40:{i:0;s:11:\"fusion_blog\";i:1;s:13:\"fusion_button\";i:2;s:11:\"fusion_code\";i:3;s:20:\"fusion_content_boxes\";i:4;s:13:\"fusion_events\";i:5;s:18:\"fusion_fontawesome\";i:6;s:14:\"fusion_gallery\";i:7;s:16:\"fusion_highlight\";i:8;s:17:\"fusion_imageframe\";i:9;s:25:\"fusion_

Then enormous amounts of this:

i:147662;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147663;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147664;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147665;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147666;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147667;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147668;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147669;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147670;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147671;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147672;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147673;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147674;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147675;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147676;s:20:\"fbmlg_mobile_layouts\";i:147677;

The incrementing number goes to 652628 and it says update_option() is calling Plugin: fusion-builder-mobile-layout-creator to create this query.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a question for the specific plugin you mention. Their developers would know best.

Comment: The fusion plugin is part of Avada's framework.  I know these plugins/theme are popular and allow people to do a lot of stuff out of the box, but they're really bloated.  Their entire business model is based on selling to as wide an array of clients as possible, so their software includes as many options as possible, and most sites use only a fraction of them.   I've also found that the longer they're in use, the slower they get.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the plugin instead of a question specifically about WordPress Development. It may be something you could bring up on their [Community Forum](https://theme-fusion.com/community-forum/). 3rd party plugins are considered to be off-topic here and questions regarding those plugins are better suited using the plugins support methods. The plugin developers or users who are familiar with the plugin/product should be able to help & answer your questions.

Comment: The Google Site Kit plugin includes a page speed diagnosis which breaks down page loading and the elements on it. It may not give you exactly what you want but it will probably point you towards specific parts of the site loading slow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as it turned out was the fusion-builder-mobile-layout-creator plugin. By going into settings for the theme and unchecking mobile layout (which checked itself again immediately), it cleared the buildup of entries. It may recur but that's the fix. We might have to uninstall the plugin entirely longer term.

Answer (score 0):

Tony Ocasu, thank you for this.  I ran into this same problem and your post helped clarify what I was looking at.  Your workaround also worked.

After exercising the workaround, it was clear the problem would be back (the options table row started growing again immediately).  There's no support from this plugin from the original authors.  Thankfully, the bug was fairly easy to fix.  Here's a small diff you can apply.

```
*** custom-mobile-post-type.php.ORIG    Mon Sep 13 14:12:28 2021
--- custom-mobile-post-type.php Thu Feb 10 18:51:58 2022
***************
*** 37,46 ****
  if( class_exists('FusionBuilder') ){
 
     $existing_settings = get_option( 'fusion_builder_settings' );
!    if( isset( $existing_settings['post_types'] ) && !empty( $existing_settings['post_types'] ) ){
!      array_push($existing_settings['post_types'],'fbmlg_mobile_layouts');
     }else{
!      $existing_settings['post_types'] = array('fbmlg_mobile_layouts', 'post', 'page', 'avada_portfolio', 'avada_faq');
     }
 
         update_option( 'fusion_builder_settings', $existing_settings );
--- 37,49 ----
  if( class_exists('FusionBuilder') ){
  
     $existing_settings = get_option( 'fusion_builder_settings' );
!    if( isset( $existing_settings['post_types'] ) && !empty( $existing_settings['post_types'] ) ) {
!      if ( !in_array( 'fbmlg_mobile_layouts', $existing_settings['post_types'] ) ) {
!        array_push($existing_settings['post_types'],'fbmlg_mobile_layouts');
!      }
     }else{
!      $existing_settings['post_types'] = array('fbmlg_mobile_layouts', 'post', 'page', 'avada_portfolio', 'avada_faq',
!                                               'fusion_template', 'fusion_tb_section', 'fusion_form');
     }
 
         update_option( 'fusion_builder_settings', $existing_settings );
```